# How to CreateMap for Entity and DTO with ICollection and IList

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper

I have a problem with mapping in AutoMapper.
I try use ForMember function, but still get a error connecting with mapping.
How to CreateMap for this Entities?

I created a AutoMapping class:

```
    public class AutoMapping : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapping()
        {
            CreateMap<Member, MemberDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Groups, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src.GroupMember.Select(x => x.Group)); });
            CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Members, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src.GroupMember.Select(x => x.Member)); });
        }
    }
```

And I tried use it like this:

```
    public async Task<Page<MemberDto>> GetPaginatedAsync(IDataTablesRequest request)
    {
        Filters<MemberDto> filters = GetFiltersFromRequest(request);
        Sorts<MemberDto> sorts = GetSortsFromRequest(request);
        var currentPage = request.Start / request.Length + 1;
        var pageSize = request.Length;

        try
        {
            return await _context.Member
                .Include(gm => gm.GroupMember)
                .ThenInclude(g => g.Group)
                .Select(m => _mapper.Map<MemberDto>(m))
                .PaginateAsync(currentPage, pageSize, sorts, filters);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex; //Log it
        }
    }
```

In next steps I will make the same with rest of my Entities, but please give me some tips :)

EDIT: After use

```
                    .ProjectTo<MemberDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                    .PaginateAsync(currentPage, pageSize, sorts, filters);
```

I get error like

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Member>
    .Where(m => DbSet<GroupMember>
        .Where(g => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(m, "MemberId") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(m, "MemberId") == EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(g, "MemberId"))
        .Join(
            outer: DbSet<Group>, 
            inner: g => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(g, "GroupId"), 
            outerKeySelector: g0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(g0, "GroupId"), 
            innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<GroupMember, Group>(
                Outer = o, 
                Inner = i
            ))
        .Select(g => new GroupDto{ 
            CreatedDate = g.Inner.CreatedDate, 
            DeletedDate = g.Inner.DeletedDate, 
            GroupId = g.Inner.GroupId, 
            IsActive = g.Inner.IsActive, 
            Members = DbSet<GroupMember>
                .Where(g1 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(g.Inner, "GroupId") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(g.Inner, "GroupId") == EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(g1, "GroupId"))
                .Join(
                    outer: DbSet<Member>, 
                    inner: g1 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(g1, "MemberId"), 
                    outerKeySelector: m0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(m0, "MemberId"), 
                    innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<GroupMember, Member>(
                        Outer = o, 
                        Inner = i
                    ))
                .Select(g1 => new MemberDto{ 
                    CreatedDate = g1.Inner.CreatedDate, 
                    DateOfBirth = g1.Inner.DateOfBirth, 
                    Email = g1.Inner.Email, 
                    FirstName = g1.Inner.FirstName, 
                    IsActive = g1.Inner.IsActive, 
                    LastName = g1.Inner.LastName, 
                    MemberId = g1.Inner.MemberId, 
                    PhoneNumber = g1.Inner.PhoneNumber, 
                    UpdatedDate = g1.Inner.UpdatedDate 
                }
                )
                .ToList(), 
            Name = g.Inner.Name, 
            UpdatedDate = g.Inner.UpdatedDate 
        }
        )
        .ToList()
        .Any(g => g.Name.Contains(__column_Search_Value_0)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

EDIT2: I use it for Paginate and Filtering:
https://github.com/wdunn001/EntityFrameworkPaginateCore/tree/master/EntityFrameworkPaginateCore

EDIT3:

```
private static Sorts<MemberDto> GetSortsFromRequest(IDataTablesRequest request)
{
    var sorts = new Sorts<MemberDto>();
    foreach (var column in request.Columns.Where(x => x.IsSortable && x.Sort != null))
    {
        switch (column.Field)
        {
            case "firstName":
                sorts.Add(true, x => x.FirstName, column.Sort.Direction != SortDirection.Ascending);
                break;
            case "lastName":
                sorts.Add(true, x => x.LastName, column.Sort.Direction != SortDirection.Ascending);
                break;
            case "email":
                sorts.Add(true, x => x.Email, column.Sort.Direction != SortDirection.Ascending);
                break;
            case "phoneNumber":
                sorts.Add(true, x => x.PhoneNumber, column.Sort.Direction != SortDirection.Ascending);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return sorts;
}

private static Filters<MemberDto> GetFiltersFromRequest(IDataTablesRequest request)
{
    var filters = new Filters<MemberDto>();
    foreach (var column in request.Columns
        .Where(x => x.IsSearchable && x.Search != null && 
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Search.Value))
        )
    {
        switch (column.Field)
        {
            case "firstName":
                filters.Add(true, x => x.FirstName.Contains(column.Search.Value));
                break;
            case "lastName":
                filters.Add(true, x => x.LastName.Contains(column.Search.Value));
                break;
            case "email":
                filters.Add(true, x => x.Email.Contains(column.Search.Value));
                break;
            case "phoneNumber":
                filters.Add(true, x => x.PhoneNumber.Contains(column.Search.Value));
                break;
            case "groups":
                filters.Add(true, x => x.Groups.Any(g => g.Name.Contains(column.Search.Value)));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return filters;
}
```

EDIT4:

```
CreateMap<Member, MemberDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Groups, 
                           opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src.GroupMember); });
```

After removing SELECT I get a error:

```
Missing map from CMSport.Context.Models.GroupMember to CMSport.Dto.GroupDto. Create using CreateMap<GroupMember, GroupDto>.
```

***SOLUTION:***
 1. Make filter and sorts by Member, not by MemberDto
 2. Set Dtos as [JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
 3. Map it after PaginateAsync like this

```
var page = await _context.Member
    .Include(x => x.GroupMember)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Group)
    .PaginateAsync(currentPage, pageSize, sorts, filters);

return new Page<MemberDto>
{
    CurrentPage = page.CurrentPage,
    PageCount = page.PageCount,
    PageSize = page.PageSize,
    RecordCount = page.RecordCount,
    Results = page.Results.Select(x => _mapper.Map<MemberDto>(x))
};
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? Also, you show a lot of code that I don't think is needed to answer the question. Only `AutoMapper` and `GetPaginatedAsync` would IMO be needed. Rest is just noise.

Comment: Can you clearly express your current code and wrong statements? Is there any error in the `GetPaginatedAsync` method? If so, where and what is the error?

Comment: When datatable is loading without filters all is ok, but when I try search by group I get error from "EDIT"

Comment: @SzymonKaszuba I've updated the answer, can you please check it out?

Comment: @E. Shcherbo  Still the same, when try to filter: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Member>... mapping error

Comment: By the way, the error appears every time you try to filter by **any** field or only when by group?

Comment: Only when by group. I can filter by firstName, lastName, email in the same time and use sorting by 2 or 3 column

Comment: Yes. I get 4 members and one of them have groups table. Try check this link with photo: https://imgur.com/VXV7455

Comment: I see. What I can suggest for now is to make mapping after `PaginateAsync` method. In this case you should declare your filter and sorting with `Member` type arguments rather than `MemberDto` and you can also use the `Map` method as it was before `ProjectTo`. At least it will help you to move on. Tomorrow, I will try to do something similar to your use case and I hope I will come up with a better solution.

Comment: I do not know that I need or do not need a SELECT. I am not sure how AutoMapper works. When I remove it i get this: Missing map from CMSport.Context.Models.GroupMember to CMSport.Dto.GroupDto. Create using CreateMap<GroupMember, GroupDto>.

Comment: You definitely need `Select` there, because the `GroupMember` type represents many-to-many relationship. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the error, I set up my project so that it uses the Automapper and PaginateAsync lib you use, but everything is working fine. Which versions of core and EF do you use?

Comment: EFC v3.1.4 and .NET Core 3.1

Comment: @E. Shcherbo Can You upload this demo somewhere and send link to me?

Comment: @SzymonKaszuba Sure, I hope this will help https://github.com/eugene-shcherbo/automapper-issue

Comment: @Szymon does it help somehow?

Comment: Sorry, but no. Tomorrow I will try make it on new project.

Comment: My demo doesn't work also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you have an error related to translating `LINQ` to `SQL`, in the

```
.Select(m => _mapper.Map<MemberDto>(m))
```

Obviously, `_mapper.Map<MemberDto>(m)` can't be translated to `SQL`, therefore instead of that line you can try to use `.ProjectTo<MemberDto>()` (see [QuarableExtensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html)) so that the query will look like

```
return await _contesnxt.Member
            .ProjectTo<MemberDto>()     
            .PaginateAsync(currentPage, pageSize, sorts, filters);
```

Comment: `Include` is not needed with `ProjectTo`.

Comment: Error CS1501 No overload for method 'ProjectTo' takes 0 arguments

Comment: You need to tell the compiler in which namespace the method is defined, so try to add in the top of your source code file `using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;`

Comment: .ProjectTo<MemberDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider) probably will be ok, but I will check it after main work

Comment: I edited my question, becouse I still have problem with mapping, but now it is conecting with filtering and searching.

Comment: What is the `PaginateAsync` method? Do you use a library? If so, what is the library?

Comment: This is it: https://github.com/wdunn001/EntityFrameworkPaginateCore/tree/master/EntityFrameworkPaginateCore

Comment: @SzymonKaszuba It would also be useful if you could provide your `GetFiltersFromRequest` and `GetSortsFromRequest` methods.

Comment: I'm assuming there is something in your filter expression, so I need to have a look.

Comment: Ok, I will add it in EDIT3 :)